# How do you add a Class that Increment to Elements that are appending with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that appends an input form field to my form. I want it to add a class that increments by 1 each time a form field gets appended.

For example.
Check out my 
https://jsfiddle.net/webtj01/aypkzgfx/

I want each time a user clicks the add field button, it would add with input field with the classes like this

```
class="Field1"

class="Field2"

class="Field3"

class="Field4"

class="Field5"
```

Comment: Why you need a unique class for each of the inputs?

Comment: I think for "for" attribute of label.

Comment: im using Mandrill mailing service to pull data from each different class.

For example, each input field is for an email, so if user adds 5 different emails, jquery has to pull 5 different emails from each form field by getting data from each different class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a variable called `x` for detecting the max count, Just use it.

```
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input class="Field' + ++x + '" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/aypkzgfx/1/)

Comment: thanks that works! I also solved it by doing

          `   $(wrapper).append('<div><input class="formfield" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                    $(".formfield").each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("item" + (i+1));
        });
        } `

too